# Library imports requires for 'Keyboard' and 'Keys'

Tags: c#, xaml, universal

I am trying to write an event handler for when the space key is pressed, but it gives the error

The name 'keys (or keyboard)' does not exist in the current context.

I'm guessing I'm missing some library imports for these two methods.

Am I right? If so what are the imports I need to make? If not what do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks!

```
private void KeysDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Return))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Space pressed in your app or pressed anywhere?

Comment: Space pressed in my App.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) `enum` comes from `System.Windows.Forms.dll`. (WinForms)

[`Keyboard.IsKeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown(v=vs.110).aspx) comes from `PresentationCore.dll`. (WPF)

Don't mix these two.

`KeyBoard.IsKeyDown` takes a [`Key`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(v=vs.110).aspx) `enum` parameter which comes from `WindowsBase.dll`, not a `Keys` `enum` parameter.

**Update**

I see now that you're developing a Universal Windows App.

You should do it like this in that case:

```
private void KeysDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

References in my project:

[image: References]

Comment: Ok, but I get the error under VirtualKey 
The name 'VirtualKey' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I created a new "Blank App (Universal Windows)" in Visual Studio 2015. Updated the answer with the references I have in the project file. I don't have any issues referring to `VirtualKey`.

Answer (score 0):

See System.Windows.Input or System.Windows.Forms depending on your application structure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When I add 
using System.Windows.Forms;
I get 
the type or namespace 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'   (are you missing an assembly reference?)

And when I put
using System.Windows.Input;
I get a green line under the whole thing, saying 
The Using directive for 'System.Windows.Input' appeared previously in this namespace.
Using Directive is unnecessary.